# D'où vient l'expression « battre son plein » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

L'expression **battre son plein** veut dire qu'une situation arrive à son point culminant, par exemple comme « une fête qui *bat son plein* », très bien. Mais lorsque je cherche à comprendre l'origine de cette expression, je trouve plusieurs pistes :

1. Hypothèse majoritaire :

   > Au milieu du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, et au sens propre, cette expression se
   >   rapportait à la marée qui, lorsqu'elle avait atteint son point le plus
   >   haut, restait un moment stable avant de commencer à redescendre.
2. Hypothèse controversée :

   > Il s'agirait à l'origine du « *son plein* » que peut sortir un instrument
   >   de musique.
3. Hypothèse plus originale :

   > L'idée renverrait à la pleine lune qui se montre dans son intégralité.

Dois-je considérer que la première hypothèse est la réponse définitive ou y a-t-il une place pour les autres hypothèses (et y en a-t-il d'autres ?) ?

Comment: À noter que l'expression _batter son plein_ n'est pas reprise dans la lexicographie de _son_ en tant que [substantif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/son/1) (alors que _son plein_ y est bein repris), mais bien en tant qu'[adjectif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/son/0). Ce qui invalide aussi l'hypothèse 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D'après le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/langue/questions.html#plein) , c'est la première hypothèse qui est correcte :

> Plein (battre son)
>
> Si l’expression battre son plein a naguère encore suscité quelques
>   controverses, tous les spécialistes s’accordent aujourd’hui à donner
>   raison à Littré. Dans cette expression empruntée à la langue des
>   marins, son est bien un adjectif possessif et plein un substantif, les
>   meilleurs auteurs se rangent à ce point de vue. Le plein, c’est la
>   pleine mer, et l’on dit que la marée bat son plein lorsque, ayant
>   atteint sa plénitude, elle demeure un temps stationnaire. On dit donc
>   bien les fêtes battent leur plein.

Comment: Intéressant. Si on m'avait demandé j'aurais supposé une origine militaire.

Answer (score 7):

*Le dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) confirme ta première hypothèse :

> battre son plein se dit proprement de la mer lorsqu'elle est haute, est couramment employé au sens figuré d'« être à son point culminant, à son apogée » (les deux valeurs sont attestées mil. XIXe siècle)

Answer (score 4):

Comme souvent en étymologie, rien n'est gravé dans le marbre : plusieurs théories tentent d'expliquer, avec plus ou moins de satisfaction, l'origine des mots et des expressions.

Cela étant dit, pour l'expression *battre son plein*, il y a suffisamment de citations récentes (XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle) au sens propre pour que l'on puisse, je pense, valider la première hypothèse.

- [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/battre_son_plein)
- [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/plein)

Answer (score 1):

Ce débat est intéressant, chacun prendra sa vérité dans une ou l'autre hypothèse, mais l'expression « battre son plein »  trouve une explication plus solide si l'on s'accorde à dire que le « son » , c'est le bruit qui résulte d'une fête, d'un tournoi ou d'un assaut militaire, quand trompettes, clairons et tambours ajoutent par leur grand bruit à la charge impressionnante de l'événement.

Chercher son origine dans le langage des marins me paraît peu crédible. Et si la mer bat son plein, c'est qu'elle peut vous empêcher d'entendre la voix des matelots, plus portés au chant de travail qu'à la littérature.

Comment: Auriez-vous une source à citer?

Comment: Pour la mer, il s'agirait plutôt des vagues, qui viennent battre au plus haut des grèves ou des digues.

Answer (score 0):

Faux débat : On écrit le pl**A**in de la marée.

Battre "son plEin" se dit du tambour frappé en son centre.

Comment: Quelles sont les sources ?

Comment: *Plein* et *plain* sont synonymes quand ils signifient *marée haute*.

Answer (score -1):

Prendre "son" comme synonyme de "bruit" me parait plus vraisemblable du fait de son association avec le verbe "battre".
Ainsi, on dit qu'une cloche bat son plein par opposition avec le son étouffé que l'on obtenait en enveloppant le battant de la cloche avec des chiffons pour sonner le glas.
Au pluriel cela donne "les cloches battent SON plein".

Comment: -1 : L'Académie française (réponse de M42) et le dictionnaire historique de la langue française (Cf Laure) font références - A l'heure actuelle, ceux qui veulent apprendre le français peuvent s'y référer sans problème. Il faut donc retenir le choix de l'adjectif : *Battre son plein*, "battre dans sa plénitude", que l'on soit bruit ou fête.

Comment: @cl-r: Toutes les sources sont acceptables, le problème c'est que cette réponse n'apporte aucun élément qui puisse appuyer cette hypothèse (qui était déjà envisagée dans la question).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je vote très rarement négativement, mais ce qui a emporté ma décision : absence de référence - exemple que je n'ai jamais entendu prononcé (ni lu) - argumentaire 'intuitif' qui va à l'encontre des choix académiques ou reconnus - arguement que l'on peut expliquer tout aussi intuitivement d'une autre façon. Cette explication a put prévaloir autrefois, lorsque la lenteur lugubre du glas sonnait la mort ou la défaite, mais n'a plus cours aujourd'hui ; de ce fait, elle peut semer le trouble dans la compréhension d'un texte.